# Agregar cdn a Angular sin descargar libreria

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, librería

Me gustaría conocer como agregar una librería en Angular, esta librería seria del caso en que no exista en el gestor de paquetes npm, se tenga acceso por una url y que no se descargue ya que perdería actualizaciones frecuentes que se le podrían hacer,

Hice pruebas con una librería y no logre hacerla funcionar en el index.html, les agradecería bastante si me comparten su conocimiento,

He investigado que una forma de hacerlo es descargarla a la carpeta assets, llamadla en el index.html como , después importarla en el componente **import * as variable from 'variableName';**, y al final solo declararla como **declare var variableName:any;**,

con esto se puede usar la libreria en el componente sin problema, pero si la libreria no existe en NPM y si se actualiza constantemente no seria buena practica hacerlo manualmente,

Acabo de probar con la siguiente libreria en mi index.html (ya probe varias y no me funciona tampoco asi):

```
<script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
></script>
```

despues la declare en un componente asi:

```
declare let pooper: any;
```

y finalmente lo muestro en un console.log(pooper) pero me manda que pooper esta indefinido, tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal o me falta algo?

¿habría alguna forma de cargarla desde la URL directo en el proyecto?

Saludos.

Comment: Creo que a tu pregunta le falta algo mas de desarrollo consulta [Como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Que libreria? Boostrap,por ejemplo, funciona perfectamente como cdn dentro de angular. Si es javascript, entonces tienes que llamar a la función con un "truco".

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por responder, quiero intentar que funcione las funciones de una libreria por cdn, ya que no pertenece al gestor de paquetes de NPM, pero sin tener que descargarla y meterla al proyecto, ya que una libreria por link(cdn) se puede actualizar en cualquier momento y si la descargo y se llega a actualizar tendria que volver a descargarla para meterla al proyecto de nuevo, he investigado que se puede poner el cdn en el index.html y declarar en un componente como por ejemplo **declare var variableName:any;** y servirian pero descargada no por URL Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa biblioteca tiene una clase llamada `Popper` así que la declaración en los archivos de typescript debería quedar así:

```
declare let Popper: any
```

Importante mencionar que se debe cargar el script antes que el componente donde se va a usar, quedando el `index.html` parecido a esto:

```
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
```

Comment: Hola Lobos le dieron al clavo con las respuestas, no sabia que se tenia que declarar la función de la librería para que funcione, realmente agradecido problema solucionado!